# How to write a Specification for JpaSpecificationExecutor?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```java
@Entity
public class Article {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String title;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters, setters
}
```

I have to write a predicate for the below query. To get all the articles if they contain the passed tag:

```java
public Specification<Article> allArticlesWithTag(String tag) {
    return new Specification<Article>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Article> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            return builder.equal(<What should be the logic here>,tag);
        }
    };
}
```

I have to write a predicate for the criteria to be used with JpaSpecificationExecutor. I am expecting a better understanding as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:

```java
public Specification<Article> allArticlesWithTag(String tag) {
    return (Root<Article> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) -> {
        // get a reference to the tags
        Expression<List<String>> tags = root.get("tags");

        // check if the tag is a member of the tags collection
        return builder.isMember(tag, tags);
    };
}
```

Read more about `isMember`: 
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/criteria-api-is-member-restriction.html

Comment: @Aditya I hope this one helped you